# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'randomSplit'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I keep receiving an error when trying to randomSplit in pySpark.

I've added these dependencies:

```
#Step 1: Install Dependencies
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.3.0/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz
!tar xf spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz
!pip install -q findspark

#Step 2: Add environment variables
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3"

#Step 3: Initialize Pyspark
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

Created the pySpark environment:

```
#creating spark context
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('lr_example').getOrCreate()
```

and added these:

```
# Import VectorAssembler and Vectors
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
```

However, every time I run this:

```
final_df = output.select("features", "medv").show()
train_data, test_data = final_df.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])
```

I get this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-e27b8ca71b51> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 train_data, test_data = final_df.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'randomSplit'
```

Any ideas? I searched around for what needs to be imported and it seems I have everything but it won't load. [Link to Github doc](https://github.com/spencer-navy/CIT15000/blob/main/Assignment5.ipynb)

Comment: Where is `final_df` defined?  I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: This means that `final_df` is `None`, not the object you expected. There isn't much we can say without knowing where it came from. But bascially, the thing that assigned `final_df` put a `None` in it.

Comment: `final_df = output.select("features", "medv").show()` This means you're assigning `final_df` to the output of the `show()` function.  Perhaps you meant to call the functions separately, like so `final_df = output.select("features", "medv")` and then `final_df.show()`?

Comment: @JohnGordon yup - that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you left out the only important line

`final_df = output.select("features", "medv").show()`

show prints the results but returns None ... so you are setting final_df to none

instead

```
final_df = output.select("features", "medv") # create df
final_df.show() # print it
```

Comment: Apologies - it is in the code but didn't copy that line here. I added here, made those changes, and now it works! Thank you! Can you elaborate on what setting it none means and why that works?

Comment: `show()` returns nothing so ... `x = whatever.show()` results in `x == None` ...

Comment: thank you! That solved all the problems.